# How can I safely delete the old kernel version from the /boot partition of my Ubuntu system?

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, boot, linux-kernel, partition

I am not so into **Linux** and I have the following problem related to the fact that my **/boot** partition seems to be full and it seems to cause a problem trying to install a program.

I am using **Ubuntu Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS**

I try to explain in detail my doubts because I am not so into system engineering (I am a software developer).

1) Performing the **lsblk** statment lists information about all available or the specified block devices.

Empirically I think that it should show the list of all the **partitions/mounted disks** or something like this. What exactly means with the terms **block devices**?

So if I perform this statement on my **Ubuntu** system I obtain:

```
root@MyServer-VPS:~# lsblk
NAME           MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
fd0              2:0    1    4K  0 disk
sda              8:0    0   20G  0 disk
├─sda1           8:1    0  476M  0 part /boot
├─sda2           8:2    0    1K  0 part
├─sda3           8:3    0   10G  0 part
│ └─vg-lv_root 252:0    0 18.6G  0 lvm  /
└─sda5           8:5    0  9.5G  0 part
  ├─vg-lv_root 252:0    0 18.6G  0 lvm  /
  └─vg-lv_swap 252:1    0  952M  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sr0             11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

So what is the difference between **disk**, **part** (it should be a partition of the parent disk), **lvm** and **rom**?

A specific partition is **boot**, this one:

```
sda1           8:1    0  476M  0 part /boot
```

that is a **sda** disk partition.

From what I know it should contains the **Linux Kernel downloaded versions**. Is it?

Ok, the mount point is **/boot** so I think that it is the **/boot** directory into my system (is it?), this is the content:

```
root@MyServer-VPS:/boot# ls
abi-4.4.0-21-generic  config-4.4.0-21-generic  grub                         System.map-4.4.0-21-generic  vmlinuz-4.4.0-21-generic
abi-4.4.0-31-generic  config-4.4.0-31-generic  initrd.img-4.4.0-21-generic  System.map-4.4.0-31-generic  vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic
abi-4.4.0-34-generic  config-4.4.0-34-generic  initrd.img-4.4.0-31-generic  System.map-4.4.0-34-generic  vmlinuz-4.4.0-34-generic
abi-4.4.0-38-generic  config-4.4.0-38-generic  initrd.img-4.4.0-34-generic  System.map-4.4.0-38-generic  vmlinuz-4.4.0-38-generic
abi-4.4.0-42-generic  config-4.4.0-42-generic  initrd.img-4.4.0-38-generic  System.map-4.4.0-42-generic  vmlinuz-4.4.0-42-generic
abi-4.4.0-45-generic  config-4.4.0-45-generic  initrd.img-4.4.0-42-generic  System.map-4.4.0-45-generic  vmlinuz-4.4.0-45-generic
abi-4.4.0-47-generic  config-4.4.0-47-generic  initrd.img-4.4.0-45-generic  System.map-4.4.0-47-generic  vmlinuz-4.4.0-47-generic
abi-4.4.0-51-generic  config-4.4.0-51-generic  initrd.img-4.4.0-47-generic  System.map-4.4.0-51-generic  vmlinuz-4.4.0-51-generic
abi-4.4.0-53-generic  config-4.4.0-53-generic  initrd.img-4.4.0-51-generic  System.map-4.4.0-53-generic  vmlinuz-4.4.0-53-generic
abi-4.4.0-57-generic  config-4.4.0-57-generic  initrd.img-4.4.0-53-generic  System.map-4.4.0-57-generic  vmlinuz-4.4.0-57-generic
abi-4.4.0-59-generic  config-4.4.0-59-generic  lost+found                   System.map-4.4.0-59-generic  vmlinuz-4.4.0-59-generic
```

So what these contents exactly represents? Are the differents Linux kernel versions downloaded on this system?

What are the difference between the **abi-**, **config-**, **initrd.img-**, **System.map-** and **vmlinuz-4** files?

**How can I detect the used kernel version?**

2) Performing the **df -h** statment I obtain this output:

```
root@MyServer-VPS:~# df -h
Filesystem              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                    477M     0  477M   0% /dev
tmpfs                   100M   16M   84M  16% /run
/dev/mapper/vg-lv_root   19G   12G  6.3G  64% /
tmpfs                   497M     0  497M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                   5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                   497M     0  497M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1               461M  458M     0 100% /boot
tmpfs                   100M     0  100M   0% /run/user/0
```

In particular I have that:

```
/dev/sda1               461M  458M     0 100% /boot
```

So it means that my **/boot** partition is completely full?

My problem is: can I safely delete all the old kernel version (the not used one) to free up space in the **/boot** ?

How can I do it?

Comment: Check out `purge-old-kernels`.

Answer (score 1):

These are many questions in one:

> What exactly means with the terms **block devices**?

[Block devices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file#BLOCKDEV) are special files that  provide buffered access to hardware devices and a layer of abstraction to the operating system.

> So what is the difference between **disk**, **part** (it should be a partition
>   of the parent disk), **lvm** and **rom**?

**disk** and **part** as you guessed are your physical disks or drives and the partitions on them. 
**lvm** is short for [Logical Volume Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_%28Linux%29). It groups multiple partitions into a single logical volume to better manage disk space.
**rom** is your cd-rom or dvd-rom drive named "sr0".

> How can I detect the used kernel version?

You can detect your current kernel in use by typing into terminal:

```
uname -a
```

> So it means that my /boot partition is completly full?

Indeed your boot partition is completely full, which will prevent ubuntu installing new versions of the kernel.

> My problem is: can I saftly deetect delete all the old kernel version
>   (the not used one) to free up space in the /boot ?

You can try to remove old packages from the system which should free up old kernels from the boot partitions. Type into the terminal this command, give the admin password, then answer "y" to remove old packages:

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

This will safely remove old kernel versions and update your boot options and initram-fs also.

Answer (score 1):

If apt is not working try, `dpkg -l 'linux-[ihs]*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\([-0-9]*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d' | xargs sudo dpkg -P`

This purge every Kernel with  headers besides your current running Kernel. If you are unsure you can look first with `dpkg -l 'linux-[ihs]*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\([-0-9]*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d'` which packages will be purged

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure The Ubuntu Way is to use the GUI package manager, but I'd just do it on the command line.

First, find out exactly what package names are installed -

```
dpkg -l | grep linux-image
```

The figure out what kernel is actually running

```
uname -a
```

Then use

```
sudo apt-get autoremove PackageName
```

Where PackageName is the name of the kernel image package you want to get rid of - it might be something like linux-image-4.4.0-21-generic.  This will remove the kernel image (your /boot directory files), the /lib/modules/kernel_version directory structure, the kernel-headers package, etc. reconfigure grub as needed and so on.