# How to safely remove old kernels headers and libraries

Tags: ubuntu

Last night our system ran out of inodes. Luckily I manage to delete few old kernels using the following steps

1. `sudo dpkg --list 'linux-image*'|awk '{ if ($1=="ii") print $2}'|grep -v \`
   `uname -r | xargs sudo apt-get purge $1`
2. `sudo apt-get autoremove`
3. `sudo update-grub`

I manage to get back some inodes but still more than 85 inodes are occupied.

Using `ncdu` I found out that the `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0.[69|71|73|..]` directories still contain a few old kernel headers.

I'm not sure if they are needed or not given my current Linux version is `3.19.0-80-generic`.

So I have two questions here:

1. Is it safe to delete them?
2. If so how to delete them?

Comment: If not a dupe, at least related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/342525/how-can-i-safely-delete-the-old-kernel-version-from-the-boot-partition-of-my-ub

Answer (score 10):

This is covered in detail in [the Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RemoveOldKernels); I’ll summarise here.

Regarding the first part of your question, Ubuntu kernels set up appropriate configuration to ensure that `apt autoremove` won’t remove the running kernel (and the latest one, and one backup kernel); so you can remove all the obsolete kernels by marking them as automatically installed (in case they’ve lost that marker):

```
sudo apt-mark auto '^linux-image-[34].*'
```

(this will produce warnings for all the kernel packages which *aren’t* installed, but they can be ignored), then removing the obsolete packages:

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

The kernel headers are also safe to delete, and are protected by the same configuration as the kernel images, so the same recipe applies:

```
sudo apt-mark auto '^linux-headers-[34].*'
sudo apt autoremove
```